# MediaPlayerElement not playing videos, in addition to not taking the path from my removeable device

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to play a video from my flashdrive using MediaPlayerElement by settings its source in the code behind. I have verified the path is correct (atleast I think it is) and is formatted like this : D:\\video.mp4. When passing this into CreateFromUri, it says the file path is wrong.

Code Behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        GetDrive();
    }

    public async void GetDrive()
    {
        StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> externalDrives = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
        StorageFolder x = externalDrives[0];
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> items = await x.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (StorageFile file in items)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(file.Path);
                mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<Grid >

    <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayer"
                Width="400"
                AutoPlay="True"
                AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not pass file path parameter to Uri for CreateFromUri method directly. If you want to access resources in UWP by Uri, there are several [URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes) that you can use to refer to files that come from your app's package, your app's data folders, or the cloud. Why don't you use **CreateFromStorageFile** method instead?

```
    public async void GetDrive()
    {
        StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> externalDrives = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
        StorageFolder x = externalDrives[0];
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> items = await x.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (StorageFile file in items)
        {
            try
            {
                mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```